# How do I disable access keys in gVim

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

I'm looking for a way to disable the access keys in gVim.

For example, when I press alt+f, the "File" menu pops up.

This is behavior that I want to remove, so I can use these keybinds for other things.

Is there a way to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to make use of the key handlers for the menu, you can configure this using the ['winaltkeys'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27winaltkeys%27). E.g.

```
:set winaltkeys=no
```

Then you should be able to use the alt key combinations for other things. However, note that alt key mappings may not always work reliably on a terminal.

Another alternative is to simply not source `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` so that no menu will be present at all (and therefore no menu keymappings will be there. This can be achieved by adding the `M` flag to the ['guioptions'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27go-M%27) setting (`:set guioptions+=M`, however this needs to be done early in your `.vimrc` config file).

This is what I am personally using, since I have no real use for a classical menubar for vim and it gains me additional space.